# When to use Redux to fetch data from api call

Tags: reactjs, redux

I adopted Redux in my project for state control, and also Axios for fetching api in action.

But I wonder when should I fetch data using API call through Redux (in action), when should I directly make the api call in component.

Is it depending on, whether I need to store the response data in Redux (for sharing among different components)? May I know any best practice for it?

API call through Redux

```
export const fetchOptions = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {

    const request = await client.query({
      query: gqlQueries.getQuery,
    });
    const options = await request;


    dispatch({
      type: types.FETCH_DATA_END,
      options: options
    });
  }
}
```

Directly make API call in component:

```
const axios = require("axios");

useEffect(() => {
    axios({
        url: 'http://localhost/graphql',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
        query: `
            query PostsForAuthor {
            author(id: 1) {
                firstName
                posts {
                    title
                    votes
                }
                }
            }
            `
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data)
    });

}, []);
```

Comment: you can also consider using a data fetching library such as https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query

Answer (score 4):

If multiple components are using the same data, redux shines there. API calls in components are preferred when you do not want any stale data to show, therefore you call api every time component mounts and your data is always in sync with your back end. There might be some other criteria but these two help me decide , where to keep the state.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on how to decide when to use which, I was struggling I must make API call through Redux once I adopt it in project. Appreciate!

Comment: Happy to help @appletabo. If you are going with redux based api vale then explore thunk as well.